# python: output like unix 'tree' command

Tags: python, unix, terminal

I'm trying to have this kind of ouput

```
├── config.dat
├── data
│   ├── data1.bin
│   ├── data2.sql
│   └── data3.inf
├── images
│   ├── background.jpg
│   ├── icon.gif
│   └── logo.jpg
├── program.exe
└── readme.txt
```

given a nested array of array etc. of string (or a json object, I'm pretty flexible on the input)

the goal being to implement the a "task/subtask/subsubtask etc." listing in the CLI for the redmine API. I'm pretty sure there's already a library for that but I can't find it (google returning mostly things about abstract tree / RB tree etc.)

Comment: That's an interesting question, but can you update it with what you have tried so far to solve it?

Comment: right now I've mostly trying to search for existing library because i have the feeling I'm going to reinvent the wheel

Comment: In that case, do note that the general SO guideline is that Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I see, my bad, here i was in the idea of python being "one way to things"  and "battery included"  there would be some standard-library things existing, especially as that output is already used by a long-running unix tool

Comment: @user1185460: This is accomplished using [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character), and aside from getting Unicode to work right (historically a problem on Unix), this is relatively straightforward for a simple tree structure.  You can probably write your own in a couple of hours or so.

Comment: Oh hey, I wrote code like this last year. [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/zBpszRvZ), I release it into the public domain. (I'm not posting this as an answer because generating a Node structure from a dict/array/whatever is left as an exercise to the reader)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(some_object)
```

[`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html) is short for pretty-print.  If you have a JSON string, you may need to pass it through `json.loads()` first.

Comment: thanks, but pretty print looks too much 'for debug purpose'  rather than a nice output for a polished output